# Evaluating a sum of expectations

Tags: probability

Say $X$ ~ $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$. I want to prove the following,

$$4E(X)E(X^2)-2E(X^2)^2-4E(X)^2+2E(X^4)-4E(X^3)+4E(X^2)>0$$

Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $4E(X^2) - 4E(X)^2 = 4\cdot\text{var}(X) \geq 0$
- $2E(X^4) -2E(X^2)^2 = 2\left[E((X^2)^2) - (E(X^2))^2\right] 
  = 2\cdot\text{var}(X^2) \geq 0$
- $4E(X^3) - 4E(X)E(X^2) = 4\cdot\text{cov}(X,X^2)$

So, writing $Y = X^2$, your expression is
$$\begin{align*}
4\cdot\text{var}(X) + 2\cdot\text{var}(Y) - 4\cdot\text{cov}(X,Y)
&= 2\cdot\text{var}(X) + 2\cdot\text{var}(X-Y)\\
&= 2\cdot[\text{var}(X) + \text{var}(X^2-X)]
\end{align*}$$
as Didier said more succinctly as I was composing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The $j$'th moment of the Beta distribution is
$$E[X^j] = \dfrac{\alpha(\alpha+1)\ldots(\alpha+j-1)}{(\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+\beta+1)\ldots(\alpha+\beta+j-1)}
$$
Expand out 
$ 4E(X)E(X^2)-2E(X^2)^2-4E(X)^2+2E(X^4)-4E(X^3)+4E(X^2)$ 
and you get a rather complicated expression in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ whose numerator and denominator have all nonnegative coefficients.

Comment: How can you be sure the $numerator$ of the expanded expression will have only nonnegative summands? (note also that I require >0, not >=0)

Comment: Robert: Did you do what you suggest to do?

Comment: Yes @did, I did (with help from Maple).

Answer (score 1):

For every random variable $X$, the expression is twice
$\mathrm{Var}(X)+\mathrm{Var}(X^2-X)$.